# DCOM access via j-interop in Server 2008 R2

Tags: java, wmi, dcom

I'm trying to access WMI via j-interop (www.j-interop.org/), wich is a Java DCOM client.
However, I always get a "Access is denied" error.

Things I've tried:

- disabled the Firewall
- set permission on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}, which is the WMI component I'm trying to access

OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

No luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try additionally the following:

- Is UAC active? If yes than disable it. (Note: You could also disable it only for Build In\Administrator or all Administrators, if you use one of these accounts)
- Is the service remote registry started? If not start it.
- Did you enable AutoRegistration? JISystem.setAutoRegisteration(true);

I hope this will help.